# Flask on Heroku with MailGun config issues

Tags: python, heroku, flask, mailgun, flask-mail

I'm having issues with my email getting to where it needs to be. I've set up the config file of my Flask app on Heroku like so:

```
class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DATABASE_URL = 'postgres://stuff'
    MAIL_SERVER = os.environ.get('MAILGUN_SMTP_SERVER', 'localhost')
    MAIL_PORT = os.environ.get('MAILGUN_SMTP_PORT', 25)
    MAIL_USERNAME = os.environ.get('MAILGUN_SMTP_LOGIN', None)
    MAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('MAILGUN_SMTP_PASSWORD', None)
    DEFAULT_MAIL_SENDER = 'myemail@myemail.com'
    MAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

with the Flask-Mail library:

```
    from flask.ext.mail import Mail, Message

    mail = Mail(app)

    def send_mail(to, title, msg):
      email = Message(title, recipients = [to], body = msg)

      return mail.send(email)
```

But sure enough, I try to send an email and it never gets there. Did I do something incorrectly? Am I missing something? (I've removed the real DB URL and email address in case you're wondering.)

Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://documentation.mailgun.net/quickstart.html#sending-messages), the correct SMTP server for Mailgun is `smtp.mailgun.org` not `localhost` and the port is `587` not `25`. Maybe changing those would fix it up. Looks like the login and password are required as well.

You might have more success using the Mailgun API instead of Flask-Mail. I found it to be easier to use in my own applications.

This is the config and a little utility function I wrote to send mail via Mailgun on Heroku using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library:

```
import requests    

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MAILGUN_KEY'] = 'YOUR-KEY-HERE'
app.config['MAILGUN_DOMAIN'] = 'YOUR-MAILGUN-DOMAIN'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    ...
    send_mail(...)

def send_mail(to_address, from_address, subject, plaintext, html):
    r = requests.\
        post("https://api.mailgun.net/v2/%s/messages" % app.config['MAILGUN_DOMAIN'],
            auth=("api", app.config['MAILGUN_KEY']),
             data={
                 "from": from_address,
                 "to": to_address,
                 "subject": subject,
                 "text": plaintext,
                 "html": html
             }
         )
    return r
```

If you login to Heroku and click on the Mailgun Add-on, it will take you to the Mailgun control panel where you can get the key and domain needed in the code above.

Comment: True but then that binds me directly to their API which I'm hoping to avoid. Using Flask-Mail I can switch smtp servers with a simple config change. +1 for answering.

Comment: Good point. Guess I don't find myself needing to change SMTP servers all that often. Edited my original answer with some ideas about SMTP.